# Generate time list in drupal

Tags: php, drupal

Is there's a way to generate a list of time (ex: 1:00 AM, 2:00 AM…..12PM) using drupal form api for a select list element? if not, what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you could use

```
foreach(range(1,24) as $time)
{
    $hours[] = date("g:i a", strtotime($time.":00:00"));
}
```